# vim move cursor to the line that the first character is that I want?

Tags: linux, vim

I known there are `fx` and `Fx` to move the cursor to the next/previous `x` occurrence in one line.but this command is in one line.

now I want to move cursor to the next line which first character is `x`,
is there any command the vim supply can achive this?

Comment: In one of your comments, you have given as the next occurrence may be anywhere. But your question says that you want to look in next line. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using search command by typing `/^\s*x` in normal mode

`/` starts forward search
`^` stands for the start of a line
`\s*` stands for none or some white space
`x` stands for `x`, the character you want to search

You may want read some vim help manuals first;
For example:

```
:help /
:help usr_27
:help pattern
```

Comment: yeah,it's a way to do it.but I want to know is there a simple  goto command like `fx` and `Fx`

Comment: @user1577263 `I want to move cursor to the next line which first character is x`  Your answer is good one. easymotion is not for that, the "next line" could be line 40918, and now you are on line 1. you know what I meant right?

Comment: @elsonwx you can create a mapping for this, expecting a char as input. If you really want it to be "short". There is no built-in "fx" like thing for this requirement.

Comment: Why do we even need a `\s` here? The pattern can be short, with just `x` alone.

Comment: @SibiCoder without the `\s*` the search won't find an indented line that starts with `x`.

Answer (score 1):

**To find a character in next/previous line**
You can use `j0fx` to search the first occurrence of x in next line.
You can use `k0fx` to search the first occurrence of x in previous line.

Explanation:

```
   j - down arrow / move one line down
   k - up arrow / move one line up 
   0 - move to first character in the current line
   fx - find the first occurrence of x in current line.
```

**To find the character's next/previous occurence in any line**

```
     /x
     where x is the character
```

Then press `n` to go to next occurrence of it. Press `N` to go to previous occurrence of it.

Comment: you may misunderstand me ,I want to move the next line is that the line which first character is `x`,not the next(linenumber+1)line

Comment: Then you may need to rephrase the question. I will change my answer too. But why don't you use `/pattern` itself and then press `n` or `N` to go back and forward? Or, do you have any special purpose or different test case?

Comment: haha,I just want to find a short move command to achieve this

Comment: if there is a short command can achieve this.it can Improve my efficiency.assume that,I want to move to the word in screen middle,and it's line number is very big(I don't want to type `ngg` to move to the line),then I can type `this short command` to move to the line,and then type `fx` move to the position I want

Comment: It takes just four keys, right? /,x,Enter and n, that too initially. In rest of the cases, it takes only one character. I think this is simple indeed. :)

Comment: So, you meant to ask for moving to the line which has next occurrence and then you will use fx, right?

Comment: yeah,but if there are a lot of `x` in some line but the `x` is not the first character of these lines,It's too slowly to move to the positon I want.